# Extension model is not loaded

Tags: php, magento

We have a development site and a production site for Magento.
Both sites have an extension called 'Affiliate Pro' installed.

I need to access the model from my script.
So I wrote a test script.

```
<?php
  require_once '../app/Mage.php';
  umask(0);
  Mage::app('default');
  $v = Mage::getModel('affiliate/affiliatecustomers');
  var_dump($v);
?>
```

It works fine with our development site but not the production site.

[development site output]

```
object(MW_Affiliate_Model_Affiliatecustomers)#117 (15) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(13) "core_abstract" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(6) "object" ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(28) "affiliate/affiliatecustomers" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(39) "affiliate/affiliatecustomers_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

[production site output]

```
bool(false)
```

The extension functions well for both sites but the script doesn't work for the production site.

What configuration do I have to check?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: This means there is something wrong with the extension, Check if the files are there, clear the cache, disable compilation. check the var log folder for errors.

Comment: Marius, you're right. It was the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there is something wrong with the extension, Check if the files are there, clear the cache, disable compilation. check the var log folder for errors.

Answered by Marius