# How to get all available models in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

To load a model in Magento, we do this:

```
Mage::getModel('module_name/model_name');
```

Let's say that I don't know the name of module and model.
Is there a way to get all available models so that I can iterate them and print each one?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a way, but I don't see a use case where you would need such a thing.
In `Mage::getConfig()` you should find a list of all model aliases. (first part of the parameter from `getModel`, before the slash).

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/models');
```

This should give you an object and while looping through it you should get in the keys the alias.

```
$aliases = array();
foreach (Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/models') as $key=>$value) {
    $aliases[] = $key;
}
```

After that you need to read the folder `Model` of each module recursively and append each file name after the slash of `getModel` parameter and match it with the alias above.
I don't have code, but this is the idea. But I'm really curious why you need this. I'm sure there is an other solution to your problem.

Comment: Actually this question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871208/extension-model-is-not-loaded .

Comment: I left a comment on that.

Comment: Thank you, Marius. I'll let you know how it will go.

Comment: Yes. It was the 'cache' problem. After clearing it, the extension is loaded. I am really grateful.